# AngularJS with typeahead does not work for angular-generated dynamic items

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use typeahead (from ngSstrap: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##typeaheads) with angularJS (v.1.2.15). I get the following error (the list shows up but it's empty):

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$sce/unsafe
minErr/<@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js:78
htmlSanitizer@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js:12790
getTrusted@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js:12954
@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js:13635
ngBindHtmlWatchAction@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js:17671
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js:12031
this.$get/TooltipFactory/$tooltip.show@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular-strap-tooltip.js:196
this.$get/TypeaheadFactory/$typeahead.show@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular-strap-typeahead.js:131
this.$get/TooltipFactory/$tooltip.enter@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular-strap-tooltip.js:164
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js:4371
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js:4057
this.$get/TooltipFactory/$tooltip.$onFocusElementMouseDown@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular-strap-tooltip.js:292
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js:4371
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:50445/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js:4057

http://localhost:50445/Scripts/angular.js
Line 9563
```

This only happens if I click on the box that is created with ng-repeat. If I create the input myself (the last line of the following code) then everything is fine - there is no error and I see the suggestions. This is the relevant code:

```
<div class="control-group children-horizontal repeat-item" data-ng-repeat="passenger in passengers">
          <!--label class="control-label" for="textinput">Departure from</label-->
            <!--span class="fleft">
                {{$index + 1}}.
            </span-->
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="airports[{{$index}}]" value="{{passenger.from}}" placeholder="Departure from" class="form-control input-xlarge" type="text" data-ng-model="selectedAirport" data-min-length="0" data-html="1" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-ng-options="airport for airport in airports" data-bs-typeahead="" autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="removePassenger($index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></span>
                </div>                

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="addPassenger()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add new passenger</button>
            <button class="btn btn-search btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search for flights</button>
          </div>
</div>

<input placeholder="Departure from" class="form-control" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-ng-model="selectedAirport" data-ng-options="airport for airport in airports" data-bs-typeahead="" type="text" />
```

Does someone know what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

> You are probably using {html:true} which relies on ngBindHtml and
>   requires the ngSanitize module.

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/356